# Create a new Patient resource referencing user id

Tags: hl7-fhir

I'm trying to create a new FHIR resource Patient using the RESTful API using the XML format. I want to store patient information using the [Create](https://www.hl7.org/fhir/http.html#create) method, but in my patient health record I also reference a user (composed of id, username and password) to a patient in the database.

How can I link the **id** of the user to the Patient resource I'm creating via REST? Is there an XML field where I should place such information?
Is it a good practice to actually use an [extension](https://www.hl7.org/fhir/extensibility.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's perfectly reasonable to use an extension for this purpose.  If you need the data to be stored in the Patient record, you don't really have a choice.  That said, be very cautious about storing password information in the Patient resource - as Patient is going to be sent all over the place.  It might be cleaner to store the references to Patient/Practitioner/etc. in your user representation than it is to store security information in your Patient structure.  (You can represent the notion of "user" in FHIR using Basic, but we encourage use of non-healthcare-specific standards in this space.)

Comment: yes. I use SCIM for user management, and store a reference to the Patient/Practitioner record in the SCIM user resource

Comment: thanks @lloyd-mckenzie for your reply, I'll stick to the extension solution for now!

Comment: I'd encourage looking at SCIM as an alternative.